# Can't create GitHub account

Tags: github

I want to create a GitHub account, but something is blocking me from doing that
[image: ‏]

As you see, it's asking me to do captcha test over and over again.
Should I report this as a bug? is this also happening to you?

Comment: GitHub has a fantastic support team that can address questions like this.

Comment: I had this issue today trying to create a new org on my existing github account. System was Windows 10 Firefox 93.0. Disabled uBO and pi-hole and still didn't work in the browser. On the same egress network via WiFi on my Android Chrome I was able to complete see and complete the capture. None of the troubleshooting steps github listed helped :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to wait some minutes and try it later. Or you can just try to do the [following steps](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/getting-started-with-github/troubleshooting-connectivity-problems#troubleshooting-the-captcha):

> - Ensure JavaScript is enabled on your browser.
> - Ensure your browser is supported. If your browser isn't supported, upgrade your browser or install a supported browser. For a list of supported browsers, see "Supported browsers".
> - Ensure your network configuration is not blocking https://octocaptcha.com/ or https://arkoselabs.com/. If you're behind a corporate firewall, contact your IT administrator to allow those domains. To verify access to these domains, visit https://octocaptcha.com/test and ensure the text "Connection successfully made!" is displayed, then visit https://client-demo.arkoselabs.com/github and ensure you are able to load the captcha.
> - Ensure your browser does not have plug-ins or extensions that may be interfering with GitHub. If so, temporarily disable the plug-ins or extensions during captcha verification.

Otherwise everything works according to the [status page](https://www.githubstatus.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I tried many times, but I couldn't create an account on Github. After that, I tried to create an account on GitHub using my mobile google chrome, then I successfully created an account in Github. Thanks.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

In Debian: `apt install epiphany-browser`

It just bypassed github's signup "barriers" in a way that fresh installations of Firefox ESR / Firefox latest / Chromium... in Debian, Windows, Android... could not!